# How to filter out duplicates while unmarshalling json into struct?

Tags: json, go, struct

I have this json which I am trying to unmarshall to my struct.

```
{
  "clientMetrics": [
    {
      "clientId": 951231,
      "customerData": {
        "Process": [
          "ABC"
        ],
        "Mat": [
          "KKK"
        ]
      },
      "legCustomer": [
        8773
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 1234,
      "legCustomer": [
        8789
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 3435,
      "otherIds": [
        4,
        32,
        19
      ],
      "legCustomer": [
        10005
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 9981,
      "catId": 8,
      "legCustomer": [
        13769
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 12124,
      "otherIds": [
        33,
        29
      ],
      "legCustomer": [
        12815
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 8712,
      "customerData": {
        "Process": [
          "College"
        ]
      },
      "legCustomer": [
        951
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 23214,
      "legCustomer": [
        12724,
        12727
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 119812,
      "catId": 8,
      "legCustomer": [
        14519
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 22315,
      "otherIds": [
        32
      ],
      "legCustomer": [
        12725,
        13993
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 765121,
      "catId": 8,
      "legCustomer": [
        14523
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I used this [tool](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to generate struct as shown below -

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    ClientMetrics []ClientMetrics `json:"clientMetrics"`
}
type CustomerData struct {
    Process []string `json:"Process"`
    Mat     []string `json:"Mat"`
}
type ClientMetrics struct {
    ClientID     int          `json:"clientId"`
    CustomerData CustomerData `json:"customerData,omitempty"`
    LegCustomer  []int        `json:"legCustomer"`
    OtherIds     []int        `json:"otherIds,omitempty"`
    CatID        int          `json:"catId,omitempty"`
    CustomerData CustomerData `json:"customerData,omitempty"`
}
```

Now my confusion is, I have lot of string or int array so how can I filter out duplicates? I believe there is no set data type in golang so how can I achieve same thing here? Basically when I unmarshall json into my struct I need to make sure there are no duplicates present at all. Is there any way to achieve this? If yes, can someone provide an example how to achieve this for my above json and how should I design my struct for that.

**Update**

So basically just use like this and change my struct definitions and that's all? Internally it will call `UnmarshalJSON` and take care of duplicates? I will pass json string and structure to `JSONStringToStructure` method.

```
func JSONStringToStructure(jsonString string, structure interface{}) error {
    jsonBytes := []byte(jsonString)
    return json.Unmarshal(jsonBytes, structure)
}

type UniqueStrings []string

func (u *UniqueStrings) UnmarshalJSON(in []byte) error {
    var arr []string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(in, arr); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *u = UniqueStrings(dedupStr(arr))
    return nil
}

func dedupStr(in []string) []string {
    seen:=make(map[string]struct{})
    w:=0
    for i:=range in {
        if _,s:=seen[in[i]]; !s {
            seen[in[i]]=struct{}{}
            in[w]=in[i]
            w++
        }
    }
    return in[:w]
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add some spaces in to your code so it follows coding standards (you can run `go fmt` too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should post-process these arrays to remove duplicates. However, you can achieve this during unmarshaling using a custom type with an unmarshaler:

```
type UniqueStrings []string

func (u *UniqueStrings) UnmarshalJSON(in []byte) error {
  var arr []string
  if err:=json.Unmarshal(in,arr); err!=nil {
     return err
  }
  *u=UniqueStrings(dedupStr(arr))
  return nil
}
```

where

```
func dedupStr(in []string) []string {
   seen:=make(map[string]struct{})
   w:=0
   for i:=range in {
      if _,s:=seen[in[i]]; !s {
         seen[in[i]]=struct{}{}
         in[w]=in[i]
         w++
      } 
   }
   return in[:w]
}
```

You may use a similar approach for `[]int`s.

You use the custom types in your structs:

```
type CustomerData struct {
    Process UniqueStrings `json:"Process"`
    Mat     UniqueStrings `json:"Mat"`
}
```

Comment: I got slight confusion which I updated in my question. I am very new to golang so might be off little bit here. I created a helper method in which I am passing json string and structure as well which basically unmarshall it into the structure. Now I am kinda confuse where to use your suggestion which removes duplicate?

Comment: I edited the answer to illustrate.

Comment: ok that cleared my one confusion but then do I need to modify my `JSONStringToStructure` helper method? How do I use your `UnmarshalJSON` method in my `JSONStringToStructure` method?
I can add same thing for integer too but as of now confuse on how it should be integrated with my helper method and how should I be using it?

Comment: You only change the struct definitions. The stlib json unmarshaler will call the custom type's Unmarshal method.

Comment: I see so pretty much just use the code I have along with yours and internally it will call custom types unmarshal method? I updated my question with the details. Let me know if that should work as it is. if that's correct then how does it work internally? I mean how does it know what to call to do this?

Comment: If a type implements `json.Unmarshaler` interface, `json.Unmarshal` will use that interface to unmarshal the fields of that type. `UniqueStrings` type implements `json.Unmarshaler`